# I forgot my falafel and shawarma wrap

Tags: food-safety, microwave

At around 2pm yesterday, I bought wraps from a street stand I'm familiar with. I brought it home... and forgot it existed. It's 10am next day, but it's untouched and as well sealed as a takeout plastic bag can be.

Normally I wouldn't chance it, but I remember a friend saying the microwave can... sterilize the food? I forgot what word he used. Should I try blasting it in there or just throw them out? I'm poor but not starving, so it's more about "I paid for that, so I want to eat it if it's salvageable"

Comment: Ye goddes, that first answer is the most scare-mongering advice I've ever seen.

Comment: Note that we can’t possibly know whether your food is actually spoiled. What can be answered, however, is whether it’s safe according to the general rules (it’s not). The “advice” about a microwave making the food safe again is widespread, but incorrect. The rest is up to you, your sensory perception and willingness to take a risk or not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is always going to be one of those, 'you'll never know until you try it' decisions.

If the temperature where you live struggles to get into double figures, I wouldn't even think twice.
If it's 32°C in the shade, you might want to remember not to leave it out next time.

I live in the UK, used to spend a lot of my time on the road. A sandwich was always fine the next day; maybe not 'delicious', but 'fine'.